# What could be the problem in my dependencies or permissions?

Tags: android, permissions, dependencies

Received a mail from google saying my app with 250K downloads is in violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement. I have used the following dependencies and permissions. Could anyone please help me point out the issue?

**Dependencies**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'
compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.8.0'
compile 'com.inmobi.monetization:inmobi-ads:6.0.4'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

**Permissions**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
```

Though inmobi is one of the dependencies, it is not being used.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of developers have been getting this lately. This is because you don't have a **privacy policy** in your play store listing. You need to add a link to your Privacy Policy in your play store listing as well as in your app.
If you don't have a privacy policy already, you can create one for free from here [FreePrivacyPolicy](https://www.freeprivacypolicy.com). Or any other website that you find in google. Make sure it includes a section that links to the privacy policy of the ad network that you use ( I am guessing [admob](https://policies.google.com/technologies/partner-sites)).

Answer (score 0):

Create a privacy policy page "explaining why are you using their device permissions : like using camera if you have an photo editor app, etc..".

you can use any free platform to make it , then copy it somewhere like : Blogger or Google sites "that's what i use".